# Commerce Kickstart change full text search product display to https

Tags: commerce, views

I am currently developing a drupal commerce site with commerce kickstart. I've set the site up so that it's mixed mode SSL using securepages, all seems to be working fine. However, I've found a bug with the full text search (used in the main products display view) which could potentially put customers off as they may think the site is unsecure. Plus the certificate does not show the EV SSL Green bar / padlock, it display's with a yellow warning.

All browsers apart from chrome work ok and from doing my research it looks like it's only the full text search which is causing the issue (when testing using chrome by pressing ctrl + shift + j it shows the error code) on line 223:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.whiterabbitengland.us/contact-us' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint 'http://www.whiterabbitengland.us/products'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a way to set the full text search over https?

Thanks
Max

Answer (score 0):

Maintainer of Commerce Kickstart.

I just checked out the site, and it's using a relative path like Drupal forms are expected to do. From your source:

```
<form action="/products" method="get" id="views-exposed-form-display-products-page" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

The search form is a Views exposed filter exposed as a block. There isn't much trickery going on with the form beyond typical site building.

Also, I did not get mixed content warnings.

Comment: Hi Matt, I found a work around which I will have to do as couldn't find any other way to fix my issue. I've added the /products page into secure modules config so that each time products page is called it redirects to https. If I left it out of the securepages config chrome thought that the page was unsecure due to the search form would have searched via http.

Comment: Thats quirky! I think it'd be a good thing to open a corresponding ticket in either Secure Pages or Search API queue (since box is from Search API module.)